# Using old macro not working in 2010?

Tags: vba

I was trying to run a macro that was designed in for Microsoft Office 2003; however it will not work in Office 2010. Is there a wrapper or some sort of way that I can enable the Office 2010 to read the code?

Thanks for your help and please explain in layman's terms since I really don't have extensive programming knowledge.

Comment: Are you sure the macro is in the document? If it's stored in the old normal.dot template then you will probably need to copy it manually.

Comment: Can you post the offending code?

Comment: What does the macro do, and in what application (Excel, Word,?).  Can you view the VBA in the editor?  Does it run but give different results from expected?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the VBA Converter Pack.  Follow the link at the top of the support page to download the hotfix.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926430/